# Edit tags after answering a question

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500944/how-to-change-the-list-separator-in-python/42500986#42500986) question , and I got 2 scores but now I checked question and saw that it is relevant to `list` too , first of all if I add `list` tag I will get 2 scores in `list` too ? if it is works in this way should I add that tag? I think it's a little cowardice because for this example I can add `list` , `string` , `split` and other tags too. ( I won't do that !!)

Comment: As long as the tag is relevant (i.e. the question is _about_ that concept), it is fine to add it. And yes, your tag score of [list] would increase by 2.

Comment: how you get only 2 points for an answer ? upvote =10, accept =15

Comment: @SagarV 2 points in tag score

Comment: @SagarV see question link , I answered question with 2 upvote